# Subdomain with Rails and herokuapp

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have followed Ryan Bates railscast on subdomains (http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains-revised) and have my app working perfectly locally.

I have deployed to heroku but am unable to get my subdomains to work. I have read about custom domains, DNS and CNAME records but I don't think this is relevant because all I am trying to do is test straight on heroku what I was testing locally. So instead of accessing *myapp.herokapp.com* I would like to be able to access **m**.myapp.herokuapp.com. Currently when I try this I get the error:  There is no app configured at that hostname.

Can anyone offer a solution?

UPDATE:

Whoops, I think this is a duplicate: [How to create a subsubdomain for an app on heroku: (e.g. sub.myapp.herokuapp.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082029/how-to-create-a-subsubdomain-for-an-app-on-heroku-e-g-sub-myapp-herokuapp-com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sub-sub domains aren't possible - you need to be using your own DNS records I'm afraid.

Comment: John - are you able to provide a reference for this information? Then I can accept it as the answer.

Comment: I confirmed with this with Heroku: Sub-sub domains aren't possible on Heroku default domain (yourappname.herokuapp.com), and you need to use the custom record for that.

Comment: @JohnBeynon - thank you so much for your answer. can you eloborate on how to use DNS to create a sub-domain. I want something like api.MyApp.com  for my api and just MyApp.com for the regulatar HTML site. advice much appreciated