# Multi-tenancy rails application to heroko deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I have developed a Rails multi-tenancy application using Apartment gem which works fine locally and I am able to test it using lvh.me:3000/ but, couldn't able to deploy it to heroku. However, heroku push finishes it the normal deployment process on terminal. Basically, what I need is; instead of accessing myapp.herokapp.com I would like to be able to access subdomain.myapp.herokuapp.com. Currently, when I try access my app url, it's redirected to herko landing/homepage, i.e may app is not configured as subdomain.myapp.herokuapp.com hostname.

Similar question asked more than two years ago: [Subdomain with Rails and herokuapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994288/subdomain-with-rails-and-herokuapp)

Answer (score 1):

To do this you will need to set up a [wildcard custom domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-wildcard-domain).

You won't be able to set this up using the herokuapp.com domain, unfortunately.

Comment: I did add wildcard domain on Custom Domain section on heroku. Such:
Domain Name               DNS Target
*.mydomain.com           myapp.herokuapp.com
And CNAME(Alias) section on my DNS provider (godaddy.com)
Host           Points to
*                 myapp.herokuapp.com
But, no luck yet! The thing is, my app should return it's landing page when there is no sub-domain. Thus, even on heroku when when hitting myapp.herokuapp.com url, it suppose to return the landing page; now it returns heroku's landing page i.e. (www.heroku.com)

Comment: Have you contacted Heroku support at https://help.heroku.com/ --> I've found them to be very helpful.

Comment: Not yet. Apparently that's my last option. Thanks!