# Can I use subdomains with my Heroku subdomain?

Tags: node.js, heroku, subdomain

I have a node app which uses vhost to manage subdomains. So, on my localhost I have:

```
main.localhost
admin.localhost
api.localhost
```

In production I have:

```
main.example.com
admin.example.com
api.example.com
```

I have a staging system on Heroku too.

so what I want to be able to do is:

```
main.example.herokuapp.com
admin.example.herokuapp.com
api.example.herokuapp.com
```

That doesn't seem to work. Is there a way of achieving it, or do I need to create a separate domain and point my nameservers there?

Answer (score 2):

Sure this is possible. But you'll need to do this via your main domain, since it appears Heroku doesn't support wildcard subdomains on the `herokuapp.com` domain. ([How to create a subsubdomain for an app on heroku: (e.g. sub.myapp.herokuapp.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082029/how-to-create-a-subsubdomain-for-an-app-on-heroku-e-g-sub-myapp-herokuapp-com))

First, set a `CNAME` record for `*.staging.example.com` to point to `example.herokuapp.com`

Then tell Heroku to route your domain properly:

```
$ heroku domains:add *.staging.example.com
```