# How to serve frontend and backoffice with a NodeJS application on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, heroku, subdomain

I am using Nodejs with AngularJS for my backoffice application.

It stays on

```
http://localhost:3000/#!/
```

But what I need is, this url points to my frontend, and a subdomain like

```
http://backoffice.localhost:3000/#!/
```

opens my backoffice.

I tried some nodejs libraries like subomain, but I couldn't target the static files.

What is the best approach?

Comment: Checked Eric Fode's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082029/how-to-create-a-subsubdomain-for-an-app-on-heroku-e-g-sub-myapp-herokuapp-com?rq=1) ? *Subdomains are currently not possible on heroku [...] and there are no plans to make it so*

Comment: Oh no, it's too bad. We will have to change it then...