# Heroku and Socket.io not listening on the same port

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, heroku, socket.io

So I am coding this web on Heroku and I try to integrate a socket into the setup. But the problem is that I cannot make both my Heroku app and socket.io server listen to the same port.

The default port for Heroku seems to be 5000 and for socket.io seems to be 3000.

If I try to change either of the ports to the same as the other, then the EADDRINUSE error pops up.

However, if I don't, then the two processes seems to operate separately

when I run `npm start`, then the terminal says

```
Listening on 5000
listening on xoxo 3000
```

And when I turned on to `localhost:3000` it actually works ( the socket.io ), but on `localhost:5000` it obviously doesn't. As a matter of fact, it also doesn't work on the Website that Heroku generated for me (only the localhost:5000 showed up)

The code lines below are from my index.js file.

How could I fix this? Thank you in advance.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path')
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const INDEX = '/index.ejs'

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'));

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('playerEvent', (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
  });
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
  socket.broadcast.emit('hi');
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on xoxo 3000');
});
 //socket.on('playerEvent', function(msg){
  //  console.log(msg);
  //});
```

Comment: You cannot have more than one process listening on each port.

Comment: @Lissy93 I made an edit to clarify my problem, could you help with more detailed solution?

Comment: Use two separate dynos or a reverse proxy. AFAIK a dyno only forwards one port.

Comment: It doesn't work with Heroku's demo socket.io site? That's weird. Are you using a single dyno? I believe it might require 2 + session affinity enabled

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommended approach for multiport app using Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690066/recommended-approach-for-multiport-app-using-heroku)

Comment: I also deployed this line from heroku instruction: heroku features:enable http-session-affinity

Comment: @jabaa I tried, it doesn't. that's weird. as i followed instruction, it doesn't even bother running the second sever in the second file i included in Procfile.

Comment: As far as I understand, you need two different apps. You can't start two different dynos in one app.